# Compare two Word Documents and track changes in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

i want to compare 2 word documents For example my first document contains text

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet. Owing to its brevity and coherence, it has become widely known.

and my 2nd document may have some changes in words or sentences for example 2nd document contains text like this.

**"This text should be highlighted"** "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. **"This text should be highlighted"** It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet. Owing to its brevity and coherence, it has become widely known. ***"This text should be highlighted"***

Now i've changed text in 2nd document document and i want to highlight these changes in 2nd document not in 3rd document, because i'm creating versions of documents 1st document will be the 1st version and 2nd document will be the 2nd version for user to download.

Please help me i want to use **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.**

Comment: i've seen some other posts related to my question but these were not fulfilling my conditions so please help me..

Comment: I guess your requirement is to keep the first version as it is and then show the changes in subsequent versions. So when you make your 2nd version, you will have to take a copy of the 1st version and then enable "track changes" on the copy(2nd version). Now you can do your changes to the 2nd version and user will see all the changes that you have made through "track changes" feature in MS word. Since you are saying that you want to use  Microsoft.Office.Interop, I guess you are already familiar with handling word docs using MS word libs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes you understand exactly what i want. but can you please give me a simple example of this in code??

Comment: I'll try to post some codes. By the way do you know how "track changes" work in ms word? If not, first you need to do it in MS word and see if that's what you want.

Comment: i'm not familiar with "Track Changes" option let me try this in MS word.

Comment: @Kosala W "Track Changes" didn't fit to my requirements :( actually i need to compare 1st version grammatically and 2nd as well at the point of creating other version i don't know what have been changed in 2nd version that's why i need to compare these versions first and highlight changes. now suggest me what should i do?

Comment: Are you thinking of highlighting changes using an overlay? Like a version control system?  I have done something similar in wpf using telerik RadEditor. They have a web version too. I know wpf version supports highlighting etc. You might want to have a look. If track changes does not suit your requirement, you will have to implement your own methods to identify the changes. If you decided to go with Rad controls you would not need office interop libs. Here is an [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Word has the Compare functionality - you'll find it in the Reviewing tab of the Ribbon, towards the right, in its own group. That lets you specify two documents and compare the content. Differences are displayed as "track changes" (reviewing) and you can specify in which document to show them, or to show them in a new document.

Try that in the Word application and if it does what you need, you can use the Word.Application.CompareDocuments method to make the comparison using the "interop".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me i hope this will help for others as well..

```
        string fileToOpen = @"d:\doc1.docx";

        string fileToCompare = @"d:\doc2.docx";

        Application app = new Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = true;
        object AddToRecent = false;
        object Visible = false;

        var doc = app.Documents.Open(fileToOpen, ref miss, readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        doc.TrackRevisions = true;
        doc.ShowRevisions = false;
        doc.PrintRevisions = true;

        doc.Compare(fileToCompare, miss, WdCompareTarget.wdCompareTargetCurrent, true, false, false, false, false);

        object SaveToFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault;
        string outputFileName = @"d:\output.docx";
        doc.SaveAs2(outputFileName, SaveToFormat, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        doc.Close();
        var word = app.Application;
        word.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        doc = null;
        word = null;
        app = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```